# Adding recaptcha into mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have added the recaptcha helper to a view I have created.
My controller looks like

```
  [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(ContactModel model)
    {
        if (ReCaptcha.Validate(privateKey: ReCaptcha.PublicKey = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RecaptchaKey"]))
        {
        }
    }
```

Everytime the validation is failing, 2 questions 
1. How do I pass the error back to view
2. Why is the result not been returned as valid when I know the key and the answer is correct?

Thank you

Comment: not implemented ReCaptcha in an MVC environment yet, but this looks like a good place to start for reference http://devlicio.us/blogs/derik_whittaker/archive/2008/12/02/using-recaptcha-with-asp-net-mvc.aspx its not MVC3 but I shouldn't think that would make a difference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That code is not setting the private key correctly (or the public key for that matter). Set your private key in your controller, set the public key in your view.

In your controller:

```
    <HttpPost()> _
    Public Function LogOn(ByVal model As LogOnModel, ByVal returnUrl As String) As ActionResult

        If Microsoft.Web.Helpers.ReCaptcha.Validate(privateKey:=System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("reCaptcha:privateKey")) Then
            If ModelState.IsValid Then
                If MembershipService.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password) Then
                    FormsService.SignIn(model.UserName, model.RememberMe)
                    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl) AndAlso Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) Then
                        Return Redirect(returnUrl)
                    Else
                        Return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home")
                    End If
                Else
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.")
                End If
            End If
        Else
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "The reCaptcha is incorrect!!")
        End If

        ' If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        Return View(model)

    End Function
```

In your view:

@ReCaptcha.GetHtml(publicKey:=System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("reCaptcha:publicKey"), theme:="red")

In web.config:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/> 
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
    <add key="reCaptcha:privateKey" value="6LceccMSAAAAAFi54eiELTCDUwrHjY-Qwot05Kip" />
    <add key ="reCaptcha:publicKey" value="6LceccMSAAAAAO9u14kcJflcpGD6XnfjNf1KcKz6" />
  </appSettings>
```

My example is in VB.NET, but you should be able to convert it easily.